# Android CheckBox uncheck

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-checkbox

I want to add save check in Android application. There are one CheckBox, two EditText. 
But all checks no effect, is there something wrong with my save check code?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
String errString = SaveCheck();
}

private String SaveCheck() {
//et_other:other transportation
//CheckCar:car
//et_mileage:mileage


CheckBox CBC = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckCar);

if (et_other.getText() != null && !CBC.isChecked() && et_mileage.getText().toString().startsWith("0.0")) {
float temp = Float.parseFloat(et_mileage.getText().toString());
if (temp > 0.0)
    return " Fill in other transportation and the car is not checked, mileage must 0";
}

if (et_other.getText() != null && CBC.isChecked() && et_mileage.getText().toString().startsWith("0.0")) {
float temp = Float.parseFloat(et_mileage.getText().toString());
if (temp == 0.0)
    return " Fill in other transportation and check the car, mileage mustn't 0";
}
}
```

Comment: where are you saving the check state ?

Comment: There is a TextView when onClick will call the SaveCheck method.

Answer (score 0):

you can save your checkbox state in sharedPreference and then use that state where you want even if you kill the app and open again then you can also get the your last checked state. This is very simple your have to create a Custom preference class and set some getter and setter and use them in your all over project:

Your Preference class;-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

            private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
            private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

            public static boolean isCheckBoxChecked(Context ctx) {
                mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                return mPrefs.getBoolean("checkBoxState", true);
            }

            public static void setCheckBoxChecked(Context ctx, Boolean value) {
                mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mPrefsEditor.putBoolean("checkBoxState", value);
                mPrefsEditor.commit();
            }

        }
```

and use this method when check your checkbox then save the state in this method :-

```
AppPreference.setCheckBoxChecked(this, your checkbox state in true or false);
```

and when you need that state then call this method:-

```
if(isCheckBoxChecked(this)){
  // this is chaced state
}else{
  // this is not chacked state
}
```

Comment: have you try this ?